# Where can I get MonoDevelop  .deb to install while off-line?

Tags: package-management, c#

I want to install MonoDevelop in offline mode on 11.04 as I don't have internet connection. I searched MonoDevelop site which is redirecting me to Badgerports but couldn't find the .deb package. Please help me find offline installer/.deb package of MonoDevelop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look here:

http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-11.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/monodevelop-python_2.4-2_all.deb.html

```
You have to ensure you get all the requires:
    libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10)
    libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10)
    libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3)
    libmono-posix2.0-cil (>= 2.4)
    libmono-sqlite2.0-cil (>= 1.2.6)
    libmono-system-data2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3)
    libmono-system2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3)
    monodevelop (>= 2.4)
    monodevelop (<< 2.4.)
```

I am not sure if there is a single .deb file that will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark `monodevelop` for installation in Synaptic, it will have an option to create a download script in the File menu.  You can use that script to download all the packages needed, then use the option just below it in the same menu to install the packages later.

The download script might not work if you don't have a linux/unix computer, but even then it should be useful as it has a list of all the .deb files you need...